# Locking the body scroll, but some div in body is possible to scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the mobile device, 
when the user touches the (.menu-btn), (.menu) is shown and the (body) is locked to scroll.

But the problem is (.menu)  was also looked too.

How can I make  (.menu) is possible to scroll even though the (body) is looked to scroll?

https://jsfiddle.net/n17qw8sb/

I know there is body-scroll-lock. : https://github.com/willmcpo/body-scroll-lock

Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to use webpack for this one :(

```
<body>

    <header>
        <h2> Top area </h2>
        <div class="menu-btn">

        </div>

        <div class="menu">
            <h2> Hamburger menu area </h2>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="contents">


        <h2> Contents area </h2>

    </section>

</body>
```

---

```
$('.menu-btn').on('click', function() {
   $('.menu').toggleClass('active');
   $('body').toggleClass('lock-scroll');
   $('html').toggleClass('lock-scroll');
})
```

---

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lavender;
}

body.lock-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

html.lock-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: beige;
  z-index: 100;

}

.menu-btn {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 300;
  top: 1em;
  right: 1em;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 130vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 200;
  padding-top: 40%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .5);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.menu.active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.contents {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50%;
  height: 150vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a `.menu-content` element and place the content of `.menu` element inside that.

And also add this style to end of your style

```
.menu {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.menu-content {
  height: 130vh;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dm8zrabx/

```js
$('.menu-btn').on('click', function() {
   $('.menu').toggleClass('active');
   $('body').toggleClass('lock-scroll');
   $('html').toggleClass('lock-scroll');
})
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lavender;
}

body.lock-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

html.lock-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: beige;
  z-index: 100;

}

.menu-btn {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 300;
  top: 1em;
  right: 1em;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 130vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 200;
  padding-top: 40%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .5);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.menu.active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.contents {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50%;
  height: 150vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

/*  newly added style */
.menu {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.menu-content {
  height: 130vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

    <header>
        <h2> Top area </h2>
        <div class="menu-btn">
            
        </div>
        
        <div class="menu">
          <div class="menu-content">
                <h2> Hamburger menu area </h2>
          </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="contents">
    
    
        <h2> Contents area </h2>
    
    </section>

</body>
```

Note: See the result in full-page view